# Running memory-intensive background task on a web server

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7

I've got a web application that is a front-end to a very memory-intensive, multi-threaded image processor. The web application is running out of memory when it kicks-off large image processing tasks.

**How can I run these tasks in a way (e.g. the background) that doesn't effect the memory allocated to the web application?**

I'm unfamiliar with this sort of problem, but I would imagine there are techniques in .NET for doing this very thing. My web server is running ASP.NET MVC4, to give you a sense of the technology I'm targeting.

P.s. optimizing the image processor is not a concern, as the command-line interface to it works just fine.

Comment: BackGroundWorker http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx but not sure that will fix your memory problem as it is still running under the web application.

Answer (score 2):

Hey we have run into similar situations, it is never a good idea to load down your webserver with memory intensive tasks. The web server is very good at one thing, serving up web pages, if you ask it to do more you are carrying a lot of overhead (webserver) to do something that doesn't need the webserver to accomplish.

What we did is set up a message queue using Redis, not sure that this is the exact one, as there are different features you may want over another, but it is enough to get your started down the path.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-redis

This is not the only queue that you can use, I believe that MS has one as well. Then we set up a server in the cloud, which was much smaller that was listening on that same queue. Once the event came through. It processed it AND...

- It was much quicker because there was no IIS overhead
- One user did not impact the experience of another user
- I could create two smaller machines to accoomplish what I was trying do with one larger.

HTH